# D3 map SVG performance

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js, svg

I've been struggling the past few days to optimize performance on a D3 map, especially on mobile. I am using SVG transforms for zooming and panning but made the following observation: the overkill comes from path strokes used to fake spacing between countries.

I have uploaded a pair of sample maps for comparison:

http://www.nicksotiriadis.gr/d3/d3-map-1.html

http://www.nicksotiriadis.gr/d3/d3-map-2.html

The only difference between the two maps is the stroke path along the country paths, and the difference in performance is even noticeable on desktop devices - but more obvious on mobile. Removing the path strokes makes mobile performance a breeze..

I tried all kinds of svg stroke shape-rendering options without significant results.

Now to the question. Is there any way to remove a thin border from each country to fake the spacing between countries instead of using a stroke?

If anyone else has a different suggestion I'd love to hear it!

Update: Attaching explanation photo.

What I have drawn is this. The red arrow points to the country joints. When adding a stroke in a color same as the background to the country paths (here depicted in dark grey color) it creates the sense that the countries are seprated - however this adds a serious performance hit on mobile devices. What I am looking for is somehow re-shape the countries paths so that their borderlines are where the blue arrow points, but without having a stroke.

[image]

Update 2: People seem not to be able to understand what I am looking for, so I am updating this in order to make the question even clearer.

[image]

Let's assume that the original countries paths are shown on the left of this image. What I am looking for is a way that I can somehow 'contract' the paths inwards so that the newly created paths shown in red, leave enough empty space between them that will 'emulate' a stroke between them.

Doing this, will leave no use to having an extra layer of strokes, thus gain performance from only using paths instead of paths+strokes.

**Update 2:** Hello again, I seem to have found a half-solution to my problem. I managed to extract the topojson to shapefile, edit the shapefile the way I want (used a program named OpenJump), but the conversion takes away all the topojson properties I need - id, country name, so I can't convert back to the original topojson.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You saying you don't need the light white border around the country in http://www.nicksotiriadis.gr/d3/d3-map-1.html ?

Comment: exactly the opposite; I want to have spacing between the countries but this spacing NOT be using stroke lines.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you maybe create a picture of what you want? And the maps are at same speed when I compared them. I did not test on mobile.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your interest. I have updated the queestion.

Comment: In addition to using topojson it might be worth simplifying path to redice number of points to make rendering faster. Check this one http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the answer. This radically improves d3 map performance!

1) I got my topojson file and extracted to shapefile using `mapshaper.org`. This gives 3 files: **.shp, .shx, .dbf** . From what I realized the **.dbf** file holds all the TopoJSON properties/attributes.

2) Opened the **.shp** shape file to OpenJUMP **http://www.openjump.org/** - Which automatically imports the **.dbf** file as well.

3) I selected the countries layer and went to **Tools > Analysis > Buffer**.

4) Checked the `Update geometry in source layer` box so that the geometry is edited without losing the rest of the attributes/properties and added a negative **Fixed Distance -0.1**. This shrinked all the country geometries to the result I was looking for.

5) **Saved Dataset as ESRI Shapefile**

6) Reimported **BOTH** **.shp and .dbf** that were produced from OpenJUMP back to **mapshaper.org** **- careful, BOTH files.**

7) Exported as **TopoJSON**. Contains new shape and all original properties/attributes!

The following link has been updated with the new produced map; we have a 'bordered' look without the need of strokes.

http://v7.nicksotiriadis.gr/d3/d3-map-1.html

Compare the performance to this link that has the original shapes + stroke. Please try on mobile to see the performance difference!

http://v7.nicksotiriadis.gr/d3/d3-map-2.html

Also, here is the updated world map TopoJSON file in case someone wants some extra performance! :D

http://v7.nicksotiriadis.gr/d3/js/world-topo-bordered.json

Comment: I apologize for the links being broken. I will try to update them soon.

Comment: Doing this just removed a radius of land around all my countries, also the performance stayed the same :/

Answer (score 10):

D3 has a thing just for that: `topojson.mesh()` (see [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference#mesh)). The idea is that since most countries share borders, there's no need to draw the shared borders twice. If you can draw each border only once, you get as much as 80% reduction in the number of strokes you have to draw. The mesh method does the javascript processing to turn a bunch of closed shapes (countries) into the multiline path of just the borders between them. You can then draw that multiline path into a single `<path>` object that you position on top of the fills.

The mesh looks [like this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6406992).
Here's [another example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/).

Comment: this sounds like a good idea, I will try this later on today as soon as I get the time

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied yet. Still didn't have enough time to look into this.

Comment: I just tried this but unfortunately, there isn't any performance gain compared to the paths having their own strokes :/

Comment: @scooterlord Sorry, that's unexpected. Not sure how much more I can help, but if you're able to easily deploy it as an example, I'll take a look.

Comment: Also, it occurs to me that for the fill (not stroke) it should also be possible to turn the entire world into just landmasses (as opposed to individual countries) by fusing the borders together. However, this wouldn't be usable if you need to have individual rollovers per country.

Comment: Finally, and you probably did this, but just in case.... Once you added the mesh, did you remember to turn off the individual countries' strokes (the one that's turned on in [your 2nd example](http://www.nicksotiriadis.gr/d3/d3-map-2.html))?

Comment: obviously I had the turned strokes off, but performance gain was not significant. On mobile it was still laggy. I have updated the original question with an example that might work. I noticed that jvectormap uses the same technique like the one I am looking for and this is why performance-wise it's great...

Comment: @scooterlord Thanks for the points! However, since it doesn't seem like I solved your problem, I would totally understand it if you wanted to keep the bounty (is that possible on SO?). Up to you. Thanks either way....

Comment: It is not possible to keep the bounty, and the system automatically gave you the points since I voted for it. It's fine man, don't worry. However I wish I could find a solution to this. However, it's not a top priority in my project currently, so I am not that worried yet...

Answer (score 1):

There might be a couple of reasons of this behaviour (on my computer, everything is working fine at the same speed ):

**Browser**

Which browser do you use ? On Chrome, your exemples are working perfectly.

**TopoJson**

eg. previous answer.

**Animation**

You are launching the animation when the page is loading. You might want to add a delay (animation().delay(in ms)). There is also a function in D3: queue(), https://github.com/mbostock/queue which load the data before launching a function.

--

If none of this change your problem, and if you want it to work fine on mobile, you can try to mix D3 and Leaflet (map for mobiles), which is great in term of performance by loading tiles.

One example:

http://bl.ocks.org/zross/6a31f4ef9e778d94c204

Hope it helps

Comment: The issue can be clearly seen on mobile - seen it on android and even on my iphone 6. The issue is seen while panning-zooming